# Best practice for storing JSON hashes to MongoDB. 1 field per key OR 1 field for whole hash

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am storing large JSON files to MongoDB.

the JSON has this structure:

```
{"listing": 
  {"k1": "v1"},
  {"k2":   2 },
  {"k3": [1,2,3]},
}
```

I am using Mongoid ODM to map the fields to my Ruby classes.

Should I create 1 field per key or 1 field of type Hash that contains the whole JSON file?

```
class Listing
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :listing, type: Hash
end
```

or

```
class Listing
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :k1, type: String
  field :k2, type: Integer
  field :k3, type: Array
end
```

My concern is that the document may get harder to query if I use only 1 field of type Hash rather than 1 field per JSON key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way to do this is:

- Add fields for keys that may be queried later and add keys for that, I don't think there would be many of them.
- Add a `listing` Hash for the whole JSON data.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think this makes sense.